# Upload and download file wrt specific version from AWS S3 bucket using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I need to upload & download document from AWS S3 bucket And that document will be updated periodically(daily/weekly/monthly depends) and consists versions to track it.

Want to write program to upload and download file with version. Not getting how we can achieve using Python and Boto3.

Thought 1)
Creating folder structure with version as folder in S3 bucket and store file in it and when user demands any version specific file will go to that version folder and get it. But what about the case where user ask for latest version without specifying? I don't want to hardcode latest version each time in UI or backend.

Ex-  S3_Bucket/Document1/version_name/file_name.txt

Thought 2)
Creating table in RDS to store version, s3 path location, uploaded date and is_latest(boll) col . Then user ask for any version or latest file, I will query data base first and then retrieve the file from S3 and share.

EX - RDS table

| Version | Uploaded_date | is_latest | S3 file Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.3.4 | current_date(default) | T/F | S3_Bucket/Doc1/version_name/file_name.txt |

These are my thoughts only, Please suggest me right or best pythonic approach to achieve this. Want to use only Python + Boto3 package.

Comment: What do you use to determine what the latest version is, the upload date, or based on semantic versioning?

Comment: @Maurice Version will be given from documentation team. So its like 1.0.1 . So i want a way to store all the versions file. At start we will get all the versions and ask user to select which version file they want to download. And they have option to click on  latest file download option too, that will point to latest version and can be downloaded directly.

Answer (score 0):

I want to offer some alternatives for your requirements. AWS S3 is able to perform versioning **[1]**. Versioning means that you may offer the same file name and S3 will handle versioning on it's side. This is accomplished with giving each version of the file a unique ID value. You can upload data to S3 using boto3 as described in their docs **[2]**. You can then download the specific version of the file using boto3 as well **[3]** by referencing it's version ID.

Identifying the S3 Object's version ID can be done in Boto3 as such:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket_name', 'key')

print(object.version_id)
```

By default if you do not specify the version ID you will receive the latest file.

References:

**[1]** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/manage-versioning-examples.html#awsui-tabs-0-4061-python

**[2]** https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

**[3]** https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#downloading-a-specific-version-of-an-s3-object

Comment: Thanks Matthew. 
But this does not resolve my query. I need to show to user how many version are there and they can choose from them and version that we are defining are like any  other software version/book/research paper. Ex - 1.2.0 or 3.4.5 . 
And as i studied versioning on S3 only Amazon S3 generates version IDs, and they cannot be edited.  In this case how i can use it for my case.